# prematurely timeout an API request from Vercel deploy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I know there's an execution timeout for serverless functions from vercel. Is there a way for me to set a timeout manually so I don't exceed this time?

For example, I am on a hobby account with a 5 second timeout limit. In my custom API route, I am looking for a way to "stop" this request before the 5 second timer, and just return an error response to my client. i.e. `res.status(500).json({error:"some error message"});`